# Rejoining after 1 year of gap in Software industry in India

Tags: resignation, software-development, india, employment-gaps

One year ago I took a voluntary resignation out of a product based company. I wanted to explore government job opportunities, but couldn't succeed.
I wanted to rejoin IT industry, but not sure about the compensation part.

Will I be paid less than my previous CTC?

Should I ask for a raise as I had 1 year of experience?

PS- Graduated on 2021 from a tier 1 college.

Comment: Looks like you'd benefit from reading some already answered questions in the related side bar.

Comment: Compensation is what you negotiate. As such, we can't answer for you. Go for all that you can get.

Comment: Either go for the highest salary you will get or be grateful that they are willing to accept you  after you abandoned them :-)  How much do they really want you?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to do some research on what the job market is paying for someone with your experience level and education. Have you applied to any positions and discussed compensation?